# TinyMCE smaller in IE than in FF -?

Tags: html, tinymce, textarea, sizing

I sized my tinyMCE boxes by using the cols and rows attributes of the textarea tag.  There's a problem, though - they look how they should in FF 4 and they look very small in IE 8 - does anyone have a clue as to why this would happen?

Comment: I haven't adjusted the CSS contained in the advanced theme at all - that's the theme I'm using.  I've checked and I don't see where I've overridden any CSS in the theme either.

Comment: How about on the `<textarea>` rather than within TinyMCE? Have you compared what you're doing with similar examples on the TinyMCE site?

Comment: I've checked my reset CSS and nothing in it that would affect the size.  I didn't do anything to the original tinyMCE package other than alter some buttons - that shouldn't have anything to do with the sizing.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by removing the sizing based on cols and rows in favor of width and height in CSS.  I guess I never realized textareas could be sized that way, I'm not sure why I thought that.  Thanks for all the help.